# Why does an AskUbuntu question mirror a UbuntuForums.org thread?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I noticed this question on askubuntu [MultiBoot with Multiple Persistent partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850319/multiboot-with-multiple-persistent-partitions) has many nearly identical answers & comments as this UbuntuForums post [Thread: Multi Boot with Multiple Persistent Partitions](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2343653).

Is there some automated cloning mechanism that copies & updates some questions/threads?

Or is it just users answering two sites themselves? I suspect it's this one, but since neither page mentions the other it seemed unusual, thought I'd ask here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the fault of users duplicating things - there's no cloning between here and Ubuntu Forums.

That said, some users just blindly copy things from one site to here without attribution, which is frowned upon - that's why the user here might not match the user on Ubuntu Forums.

Comment: At some point  someone might have thought: oh this might be a good question on askubuntu and then PM the users that answered to post their answer. Upvotes and accepted answer rakes in some easy rep.

Comment: Which is hilarious, because rep isn't real :)

Comment: Thanks, it was the "without attribution" part that was the most confusing. I've seen bad websites basically copying & stealing stackexchange information before, but ubuntu forums isn't one of those. (Was almost a toss-up to pick a correct answer, but user error takes it. Both answers get upvoted though, since @RolandiXor is [pretty much right](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RkMgAzpcI8k) )

Comment: It should be noted that in this case both the OP and one answering user match on the two sites. :)

Answer (score 12):

I regularly see the same question asked by the same user in both places. I think they believe that it increases the chance for a good answer as more eyes see it. It probably does. I can't blame them for trying.

In fact, in my particular area of limited expertise, there are several users that are frequent answerers at both places as well. Because of this, a question posted at both places may get a few new eyes, but not *all* new eyes.

If I can answer the question at askubuntu and then see the exact same question at ubuntuforums, I answer there by referring the user to my answer at askubuntu.